# Nested aggregate functions, Max(Avg()), in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm writing this query in SQL :

```
select MAX(AVG(salary) ) from employees group by department_id;
```

First I will get groups by `department_id` , but next what will happen ?

Comment: Are you getting an error or unexpected result?

Comment: It will fail.  You can't nest aggregate functions, and must instead place the inner one in a subquery.

Comment: This is invalid in all 4 RDBMS available to test on SQLFiddle.com http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a123/2

Comment: I take it back - Oracle permits it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7a123/2

Comment: @StingyJack no I'm not getting error but I don't understand the result how it works

Comment: yes @MichaelBerkowski oracle permits it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you have something like this

```
EmployeeId DepartmentId Salary
    1          1         10              
    2          1         30
    3          2         30
    4          2         40
    5          2         20
    6          3         40
    7          3         50
```

after grouping

```
DepartmentId    AVG(Salary) 
    1             (10+30)/2 = 20
    2             (30+40+20)/3 = 30
    3             (40+50)/2= 45
```

So the query below will return 45 as Maximum average salary for departmentId 3

```
SELECT MAX(x.avg) 
FROM ( SELECT AVG(salary)as avg FROM employees group by department_id)x;
```

Comment: I don't believe this is true in every RDBMS. @nikola-mitev Which RDMBS enables you to combine two aggregates?

Comment: Oracle lets you do that. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a123/2
We can have nested aggragates

Answer (score 7):

Most likely, dependent on your RDBMS, this will need to bedone with a sub-query

```
select max(AveragesByDept.avgSalary) 
from ( 
    select avgSalary=avg(salary) 
    from employees
    group by department_id
    ) AveragesByDept
```

Comment: Why do you have group by EmployeeID? It will give entirely different results. It should be on DepartmentId ...

Comment: @NitinMidha absolutely right. department_id is right. my mistake.

Comment: Just to note that needing a subquery is RDBMS dependent

Comment: What does this M at the end mean?

Comment: @h8red the M is an alias for the entire subquery expression. I can rewrite to be more explicit, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by just getting one row.  For example:

```
select AVG(salary)
from employees
group by department_id
order by avg(salary) desc
limit 1
```

The `limit 1` might be `top 1` (SQL Server) or a subquery with `rownum = 1` (Oracle).

Comment: +1 clever. No subquery necessary.

Comment: ... except in Oracle prior to 12c, which would require a subquery and rownum <= 1 predicate :(

Answer (score 1):

It's dependent on RDBMS support, but if it is supported you'll get the largest of the departmental averages for the salary.

The group by is applied to the inner aggregate, and the outer aggregate is ungrouped.

Comment: I don't know of an RDBMS which actually supports this though...

Comment: so in the end i will get a number or table ? thank you.

Comment: Under the ANSI standard you'll get a single row and a single column, even if the table is empty, because a projection only of aggregate functions always returns a single row. Oracle supports this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aeff1/3