# avg() of count of selected rows per month in a year

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to return avg() of count of selected rows per month in a year per system from an Access query that looks like that:

```
SELECT backlog.System, 
    DatePart('yyyy',[Create Date]) AS [Year], 
    DatePart('m',[Create Date]) AS [Month], 
    Count(backlog.[Ticket ID]) AS [Count of Registered] 
FROM backlog 
GROUP BY backlog.System, 
    DatePart('yyyy',[Create Date]), 
    DatePart('m',[Create Date]);
```

Results:

```
- Col1 | Year | Month | Count 
- System1 | 2013 | 1 | 25 
- System1 | 2014 | 1 | 12 
- System1 | 2014 | 2 | 6 
- System2 | 2013 | 1 | 4 
- System2 | 2013 | 2 | 56
```

I would like to get this:

```
- Col1 | Year | Month | Count | Average
- System1 | 2013 | 1 | 25 | 25
- System1 | 2014 | 1 | 12 | 9
- System1 | 2014 | 2 | 6 | 9
- System2 | 2013 | 1 | 4 | 30
- System2 | 2013 | 2 | 56 | 30
```

Comment: would be helpful to see the sql code of your query

Comment: maybe a hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030062/nested-aggregate-functions-maxavg-in-sql

Comment: here's the code:
SELECT backlog.System, DatePart('yyyy',[Create Date]) AS [Year], DatePart('m',[Create Date]) AS [Month], Count(backlog.[Ticket ID]) AS [Count of Registered]
FROM backlog
GROUP BY backlog.System, DatePart('yyyy',[Create Date]), DatePart('m',[Create Date]);

Answer (score 1):

I've found that ms-access queries can be long and tedious. You sometimes have to be creative with them. Usually what helps me is using subqueries. If that doesn't quite work you may need to break it down into a few different tables and have them access the data in one another. You can save dynamic queries as a table name and reference them in another query.

I think you can also clean up your SQL by using the YEAR() and MONTH() functions. For example:

```
SELECT backlog.System, YEAR([Create Date]) AS [Year], 
      MONTH([Create Date]) AS [Month], Count(backlog.[Ticket ID]) AS [Count of Registered] 
FROM backlog 
GROUP BY backlog.System, YEAR, MONTH;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing *average of what*, it could be:

```
SELECT 
    backlog.System, 
    DatePart('yyyy',[Create Date]) AS [Year], 
    DatePart('m',[Create Date]) AS [Month], 
    Count(*) AS [Count of Registered] 
    Avg([Registered]) AS AvgRegistered
FROM 
    backlog 
GROUP BY 
    backlog.System, 
    DatePart('yyyy',[Create Date]), 
    DatePart('m',[Create Date]);
```